# Restrict app for iPhone devices lower than iPhone 5 with iOS 8 or 7 in AppStore

Tags: iphone, ios8, app-store

I planned to develop application with targeted devices **iPhone 5/5S, iPhone 6/6+** . I don't want my application to be runnable on iPhone 4S. Can i able to achieve that?

I googled some sites , they were mentioned that we can restrict older version mobiles like iPhone 3GS using front camera or other new features.
 But in my case iPhone 4S is capable of upgrading OS version upto 8, Is there a way to restrict application for iPhone 4S ?

Need your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is not. if your app supports iOS8 it must run on all devices which support that OS. iPhone 4S included.

Comment: Nope. Apple will reject the app.

Comment: No problem, You can mark this as answered to help others with the same question if it helped you.